# Fast implementations in Python to compute the mean of products

Tags: python, numpy, covariance

I have a list of float elements `x=[0.1, 2, 0.5, ...]` with length `l=len(x)`. I am looking for fast/vectorized implementations to compute mean of the products between all two pairs from `x`:

```
S=0.0
for x1 in x:
    for x2 in x:
        S+=x1*x2/(l*l)
```

This would essentially be the sample covariance of `x`. I looked into `numpy`'s `cov()` function, however, that computes a covariance matrix, or, in the case of a list, simply the sample variance. Also, the `correlate()` function uses samples from a sliding window, not the combination of all element pairs from the list.

**Edit:** Although not stated in the original question, methods not involving l^2 memory would be greatly appreciated. `np.outer` and numpy broadcasting proposed below both have l^2 memory requirements which make them unfeasible for large l.

Comment: `np.outer(x, x).mean()`

Answer (score 4):

You can do the calculation you're asking about with simple numpy broadcasting operations:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.asarray([0.1, 2, 0.5])
l = len(x)

S = np.sum(x[:, None] * x[None, :]) / l**2
```

Comment: You could even simplify that to `np.mean(x[:, None] * x[None, :])`.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `np.multiply.outer(x, x).mean()` will do it.

For example, here's your calculation:

```
In [17]: x = [0.1, 2, 0.5, 3, 0.25, 1]

In [18]: l = len(x)

In [19]: S=0.0
    ...: for x1 in x:
    ...:     for x2 in x:
    ...:         S+=x1*x2/(l*l)
    ...: 

In [20]: S
Out[20]: 1.3034027777777775
```

And here's `np.multiply.outer(x, x).mean()`:

```
In [21]: np.multiply.outer(x, x).mean()
Out[21]: 1.3034027777777777
```

@Blckknght's answer also works just as well.